# Real analysis (Ordered field property )

Tags: analysis

Suppose  a and b are elements in an ordered field, with a < b. Show that there are infinitely many elements between a and b.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT.** Consider $\dfrac{a+b}{2}$. Where do you think it should be in this ordering? Prove this intuition, being sure to also justify that $(a+b)/2$ is in the field.

Comment: Yes this is my problem  that how i prove a+b/2 is an element  of order field??

Comment: @Balo Hint: It's a field and it must be characteristic 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For infinitely many ordered field elements between $a$ and $b$, consider $$\dfrac{a+nb}{n+1}$$